# GeoDjango Get all records of a model that are within a given distance to any of the points of a given set of locations

Tags: django, postgresql, gis, postgis, geodjango

I am trying to get the list of `person(s)` that are within a distance of 500m to a `poi`.

I can achieve this goal in PostGIS as:

```sql
    SELECT DISTINCT public.dbconn_person.id, 
        public.dbconn_person.name, 
        public.dbconn_person.location, 
        public.dbconn_poi.id, 
        public.dbconn_poi.name, 
        public.dbconn_poi.location
    FROM public.dbconn_person
    INNER JOIN public.dbconn_poi on st_dwithin(public.dbconn_person.location::geography,     public.dbconn_poi.location::geography, 500);
```

The point is that I am trying to use the same query in Django and I am facing some problems.

**models.py**

```py
    class Person(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length = 120)
        location = models.PointField()

    class Poi(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length = 120)
        location = models.PointField()
```

**view.py**

```py
    listpoi = Poi.objects.all()
    listperson = Person.objects.all()
```

I expected that something like this would work,

```py
    poi_filter = Person.objects.filter(location__dwithin=(Poi.objects.only('location'), 500))
```

As far as I have read, it seems that the location_dwithin function only accepts single points. Is this correct? Is there any way I can achieve my SQL result using Django?

Answer (score 0):

ST_DWITHIN also doesn't accept lists, but your query doesn't provide lists either. Because it is the join condition, a 1-on-1 comparison is made from row to row.

Django's ORM doesn't provide a way for arbitrary joins, other then using `.extra()`:

```py
poi_table = Poi._meta.db_table
person_table = Person._meta.db_table
joined = Person.objects.extra(
    select={"poi": f"{poi_table}.name"},  # Add more fields as needed
    where=[
        f"ST_DWITHIN({person_table}.location::geography,"
        f" {poi_table}.location::geography, 500)"
    ],
    tables=[poi_table],
)
```

This isn't ideal, but should work for your purpose.

Comment: I had heard about ```.raw()``` but not about ```.extra()```. I was able to reproduce my query with raw without problem, but it seems that performance is at stake. I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636859/django-why-is-foo-objects-extra-so-much-faster-than-foo-objects-raw. I will try your approach and compare results and times. Thanks

Comment: Extra is halfway between raw and full orm. In both cases you will loose function abstraction and tie yourself to the database implementation. I've looked into [`FilteredRelation`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#filteredrelation-objects), but couldn't make it work and felt like using a fork to drink coffee. The performance problem shouldn't apply in either case, as long as you fetch all columns you plan to render (and alias them on duplicate names).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a MultiPoint object from POIs, then apply spatial lookup function like distance as in your case.

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import MultiPoint

points = tuple(Poi.objects.values_list("location", flat=True))
multipoint = MultiPoint(*points)
    
poi_filter = Person.objects.filter(location__dwithin=(multipoint, 500))
```